# Merge files based on a list of pairs

Tags: linux

I have files in a directory, and a list of pairs of filenames e.g.

```
list:
FileA File1
FileB File2
FileC File3
```

I would like to merge each pair of files into one file. I learned that it's possible to merge all files in a directory based on a list using this command

```
xargs < list.text cat > merged_file.txt
```

But I am not sure how to do this on a line by line basis (i.e pairing up files) as in my case.

The resulting files should be called FileA_File1_merged.txt

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more?
You can read the list file which lists the files to be merged in a script and then user the names with `cat` with the appropriate ordering and store in the merged file.

Comment: What should be the names of the resulting files?

Answer (score 1):

Read the `list` file line by line, and `cat` files to a merged one:

```
while read line; do
        cat $line > "$line.merged"
done < list
```

**Attention** result file name will contain spaces and `.merged` "extension". To replace spaces w/ `-` you may use bash pattern replacement: `... >"${line/ /-}.merged"`.